# Método renameTo() de la clase File

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy intentando realizar una copia de seguridad (**backup**).

Quisiera, que una vez tenga el archivo **.sql**, generado al pulsar el evento `ActionPerformed()`, realice las siguientes comprobaciones:

- Si el fichero **.sql** está abierto y se pulsa de nuevo el botón, mensaje por pantalla (`JOptionPane`).
- Si el fichero **.sql** está cerrado, lo sobreescriba.

¿Por qué funciona indebidamente el método **renameTo()** de la clase `File` en mi ejemplo? Siempre genera el archivo **.sql**, esté el documento abierto o cerrado.

**Código:**

```
private void button_backupActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String dia = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
    Month mes = LocalDate.now().getMonth();
    String ano = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    try{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        File backupFile = new File(""+dia+"_"+mes+"_"+"_"+ano+".sql");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(backupFile);
        File sameFileName = new File(""+dia+"_"+mes+"_"+"_"+ano+".sql");

        Process child = runtime.exec("C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump --opt --password= --user=root --databases agenda -R"); 
        InputStreamReader irs = new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(irs);
        if(backupFile.renameTo(sameFileName)){
            String line;
            while( (line=br.readLine()) != null ) {
                fw.write(line + "\n");
            }
            fw.close();
            irs.close();
            br.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup generado correctamente.", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            //Abrimos el fichero creado (backup con extension .sql).
            try{
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+backupFile);
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encontró el archivo.");
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe cerrar el fichero...");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Motivo: "+e.getMessage(), "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Antes que nada decirte que no entiendo qué sentido tiene renombrar un archivo con su mismo nombre. No obstante, este método es dependiente de la plataforma por lo que su comportamiento puede variar de una a otra. Quizás en la plataforma donde estás ejecutando tú código no de problemas porque al final, como el nombre actual y el nuevo son iguales, no haga nada y te diga OK (en Windows funciona así y de seguro que en los principales sistemas operativos también).

Comment: @E.Betanzos Entonces, dependiendo qué sistema o plataforma se utilice, ¿es mejor usar un método u otro, Por ejemplo: "FileLock() o renameTo()?

Comment: La propia documentación del método `File#renameTo()` dice que si quieres una alternativa independiente de la plataforma uses `Files#move()`. Ahora bien, la documentación de este otro método dice que si el archivo de destino es el mismo que el de origen (que es lo que estás haciendo tú) el método no tendrá efecto.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Gracias por tu consejo y tus explicaciones; sí, mi caso sería el segundo.